# Finding Thevenin equivalent circuit when there are only current dependent and independent source

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

this is my first time posting. Trying to solve this question but I don't think I can do it without voltage source, can adding a fictional voltage source of 1V solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Why not add a fictional voltage source of 1 pico volt then the error it introduces is of no consequence.

Comment: The voltage across the 2 Ohm resistor is 2*i. The voltage across the dependent source is also 2*i. So if you label **b** as ground (0 V) and call the node pointed at by the current source as **x**, then the voltage at **a** must be x+x or 2x. 2x divided by 4 Ohms gives the same current **i** as in the 2 Ohm resistor. So half of the 5 A goes through the 2 Ohm resistor and half goes through the 4 Ohm resistor. So x=2.5 A * 2 Ohm = 5 V and therefore a = 10 V. Don't even need a piece of paper for this.

Comment: Xie, in case it isn't clear, examine [this info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTpc2.png).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOC5yB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{a}&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_0
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_1\$.

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{a}&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_0
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ia == I1 + I4, I4 == I2 + I3, 0 == I0 + I2 + I3, 
   I1 == Ia + I0, I1 == V1/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == V2/R3, 
   V2 - V1 == n*I1}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> -((Ia (n + R1) (R2 + R3))/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3)), 
  I1 -> (Ia R2 R3)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  I2 -> (Ia (n + R1) R3)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  I3 -> (Ia (n + R1) R2)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  I4 -> (Ia (n + R1) (R2 + R3))/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  V1 -> (Ia R1 R2 R3)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  V2 -> (Ia (n + R1) R2 R3)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2\$ and letting \$\text{R}_3\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{I}_\text{a}\text{R}_2\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_1\right)}{\text{n}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_3\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\text{I}_\text{a}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_1\right)}{\text{n}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(Ia (n + R1) R2 R3)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), 
  R3 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(Ia (n + R1) R2)/(n + R1 + R2)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(Ia (n + R1) R2)/((n + R1) R2 + (n + R1 + R2) R3), R3 -> 0]]

Out[3]=Ia

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=((n + R1) R2)/(n + R1 + R2)
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=10\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=5\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=2\space\Omega\tag9$$

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you are right, but I will have to confirm the answer next Monday.

Comment: @XieHanFoo It is right, I know for sure ;).

Answer (score 0):

The 5A current source is an independent source. An independent voltage source is not a requirement for a circuit to be valid. All of the circuit laws you have learned are perfectly valid without a voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

Some guidance:

Dependent sources rule out all easy circuit transformations which would change the topology where the dependencies are defined. You cannot for ex. change the 5A current source and the leftmost resistor to a voltage source plus a series resistor.

But you can at first let the output ab be open and calculate the unloaded Vab. That's the wanted Vth, your equivalent Thevenin source voltage. It will be =10V.

Then you can short terminals a and b and calculate the short circuit current Ik. It will be 5 amperes. The equivalent Thevenin resistance is Vth/Ik.

Current i has different values when terminals a and b are open and when they are shorted.

Note that there's already given a well crafted symbolic solution which covers what I have said.

Answer (score -3):

Using Norton-Thevenin equivalent circuits, you can reduce it like so (in terms of i):

1. Norton to Thevenin conversion of the current source and 2R resistor.
2. Combine the series voltage sources.
3. Thevenin to Norton conversion of the voltage source and 2R resistor.
4. Combine the parallel resistances.
5. Norton to Thevenin conversion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLrU5Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, combine with a nodal analysis to get the output resistance in terms of i:

$$ R_{ab} = \frac{V_{ab}}{I_{ab}} $$
KCL at a: $$ 5 + I_{ab} = i + \frac{V_{ab}}{4} $$
$$ \Rightarrow I_{ab} = i + \frac{1}{4}V_{ab} - 5 $$
KVL at ab: $$ V_{ab} = 2i + 2i = 4i $$
$$ \Rightarrow I_{ab} = i + \frac{1}{4}4i - 5 $$
$$ \Rightarrow I_{ab} = 2i - 5 $$
$$ \Rightarrow R_{ab} = \frac{4i}{2i - 5} $$

Then, from our above circuit, we know that
$$ R_{TH} = \frac{4}{3} = \frac{4i}{2i - 5} = R_{ab} $$
$$ \Rightarrow i = 5 $$

Leaving us with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe6bSo.png)</sup>

Comment: No, that's not at all correct. For example, a dead short between **a** and **b** should yield 5 amps through the short. That's already enough to show your final result is wrong.

Comment: This is not the right answer.

Comment: The first conversion has already gone wrong, because the *i* that controls the dependent source is no longer anywhere in the circuit.